# Printing out multiplication table in python

Tags: python, multiple-columns, nested-loops

[Currently I'm doing this problem and I've ran into errors.](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/23/)

I decided to practice my nested for loop logic with somewhat of a more complicated strategy even though there are several easier methods. I'm a beginner coder so I hope my documentation is not confusing on my thought process.

```
import sys
matrix = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

#This forloop will multiply the matrix from 1 to 12
for multiplier in range(1,13):
    #This forloop will increment and shift the view to each matrix cell from [0] to [11]
    for counter in range(0,12):

        #This will multiple every row by 'multiplier'
        #matrix[0]*1,matrix[1]*1,matrix[2]*1...matrix[11]*1
        #matrix[0]*2 ...                    ...matrix[11]*2
        #   .   .                                   .
        #   .               .                       .
        #   .                               .       .
        #matrix[0]*12...                    ...matrix[11]*12

        sys.stdout.write(str(matrix[counter]*multiplier))

        #Since each number (is) formatted to a width of 4' then 1 digit numbers will
        #have 3 spaces, 2 digit numbers will have 2 spaces, 3 digit numbers will have
        #only 1 space left. So the length of the numbers will be called and subtracted
        #from 4 to create the appropriate amount of spaces. Example will be:
        #
        #3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36 (there are only 2 spaces between 12 and 15)
        #12  24  36 48  60  72  84  96 108 120 132 144 (there is only 1 space between 108 and 120)
        sys.stdout.write(int(4)-len(matrix[counter])*+" ")

    #Adds a new line after finishing a row
    print("")
```

Here is my current output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<File location>", line 29, in <module>
    sys.stdout.write(int(4)-len(matrix[counter])*+" ")
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried quick fixes such as changing len(matrix[counter]) into an int but results in the same error message.

---

I also tried the following

```
    sys.stdout.write(str(matrix[counter]*multiplier))
    sys.stdout.write(int(4)-len(int(matrix[counter]))*+" ")
print("")
```

Which gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
1  File "<File location>", line 29, in <module>
    sys.stdout.write(int(4)-len(int(matrix[counter]))*+" ")
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

Final Solution:

```
import sys
matrix = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
for multiplier in range(1,13):
    for counter in range(0,12):
        sys.stdout.write('{:>4}'.format( str(matrix[counter]*multiplier) ))
    print("")
```

Output:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24
   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36
   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48
   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60
   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72
   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84
   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96
   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  99 108
  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120
  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99 110 121 132
  12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96 108 120 132 144

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Python can handle string formatting for you. Replace both your `sys.stdout.write` lines with following code

```
 sys.stdout.write( '{:4d}'.format(matrix[counter]*multiplier) )
```

This snippet uses new string formatting mechanism, which was introduced in Python 2.6.  In this case we tell Python to output decimal integer (`d`) constrained to a specific width.

String formatting syntax is described in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). However I recommend you to take a look at [pyformat.info](http://pyformat.info/) site for a clean set of examples

Comment: It worked!

Would you mind explaining the syntax to me?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting `str` to the integer as such:

```
sys.stdout.write(int(4)-len(str(matrix[counter]))*+" ")
```

Comment: Here's my output:

`sys.stdout.write(int(4)-len(str(matrix[counter]))*+" ")
'TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

`Process finished with exit code 1